# Sort properties given attribute paramter order

Tags: c#, sorting, properties, attributes

I want to sort properties based off an attribute parameter `Order` that is given.

**Attribute:**

```
public class Items: Attribute
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public Items(int order)
    { 
      this.Order = order;
    }
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
public class client
{
   [Items(1)]
   public string fName {get; set;}

   [Items(3)]
   public string lName {get; set;}

   [Items(2)]
   public string mName {get; set;}
}
```

**Get all Properties:**

```
var properties = typeof(client).GetProperties().Where(
prop => prop.IsDefined(typeof(Items), false));
```

**Sort by Order#?**

This is what I tried but it does not work

```
Array.Sort(properties, delegate (Items x, Items y) 
{ return x.Order.CompareTo(y.Order); });
```

How do I sort the properties based off the Order?

This has been solved, but would like to extend the question.

[Is there a way to sort properties without having to put an "Order" on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39426244/is-there-a-way-to-sort-properties-without-having-to-put-an-order-on-them). I am wanting to just have an attribute "EndOfList" Or "Last" that would state be sure to sort these last. So that I would not have to clutter up the code with Orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq and `OrderBy`

```
var sorted = properties
    .OrderBy(p => ((Items)p.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                           .FirstOrDefault(a => a is Items)).Order);
```

This results in following order: `fName`, `mName`, `lName`.

So what happens inside the OrderBy: access custom properties. Find a first that is of type `Items` and use the `Order` property as a sort parameter.

To sort in reversed order just use `OrderByDescending`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
var properties = typeof(client).GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.IsDefined(typeof(Items), false));
var sortedProperties = properties.OrderBy(x =>  ((Items)x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Items), false).FirstOrDefault()).Order);
```