# Is there a way to sort properties without having to put an "Order" on them?

Tags: c#, sorting, properties, attributes

We have figured out how to sort properties given an "Order" [attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39421705/sort-properties-given-attribute-paramter-order).

But is there a way to sort properties without having to put an "Order" on them. I am wanting to just have an attribute "EndOfList" Or "Last" that would state be sure to sort these last. So that I would not have to clutter up the code with Orders.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "putting an order on them." If you List.Orderby(p=>p.ProprtyName).ThenBy(p=>p.OtherPropertyName), it doesn't modify the data in any way. Maybe I'm missing what you mean by "putting an order on them?"

Comment: Did you see my Order attribute example? Instead of orderby then by. I would like an orderby all except these leave these for last.

Comment: No -sorry. the hyperlinks on my screen are very difficult to determine -- I didn't see that you'd added one in your question. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

**We can alter the Attribute class.**

```
public class Items : Attribute
{
    public bool Last { get; set; }
    public Items(bool last = false)
    {
        this.Last = last;
    }
}
```

**Then Alter the main class**

```
public class client
{
    [Items]
    public string fName { get; set; }

    [Items(true)]
    public string lName { get; set; }

    [Items]
    public string mName { get; set; }
}
```

**Then alter the sort**

```
var sorted = properties
.OrderBy(p => ((Items)p.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                       .FirstOrDefault(a => a is Items)).Last);
```